# Unable install SQLserver tool in ubuntu 20

Tags: sql-server, bash, ubuntu, installation

I installed SQLserver in my ubuntu. But when I install sqlserver-tool something happened.
type

```
sudo apt-get install unixodbc-dev
```

return

```
eading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 unixodbc-dev : Depends: unixodbc (= 2.3.7)
                Depends: odbcinst1debian2 (= 2.3.7) but 2.3.6-0.1build1 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

so that I tried below

```
sudo apt-get install unixodbc
```

returns

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 unixodbc : Depends: odbcinst1debian2 (>= 2.3.7) but 2.3.6-0.1build1 is to be installed
            Depends: libodbc1 (>= 2.3.7) but 2.3.6-0.1build1 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

and lastly

```
sudo apt-get install odbcinst1debian2
```

return

```
eading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 odbcinst1debian2 : PreDepends: multiarch-support but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I completely stacked and have no idea at all.
Dose anybody can help for me. Thanks.

Comment: Better to ask at https://unix.stackexchange.com/ |  https://superuser.com/

Answer (score 18):

User rim96 has right, the reason is that Microsoft's source list includes unixodbc in higer version (2.3.7) that depends on multi-arch (unlike Ubuntu's version 2.3.6)
I think that unixodbc 2.3.6 is good enough. In my case the follow steps helped me.

Remove Microsoft's source list.

```
mv /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mssql-tools.list ~/
```

Update sources

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Install unixodbc 2.3.6 from Ubuntu repository

```
sudo apt-get install unixodbc
```

Move Microsoft's source list back

```
mv ~/mssql-tools.list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/
```

Update sources again

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Install mssq-tools (or whatever you want) from Microsoft's repository

```
sudo apt-get install mssql-tools
```

Comment: On a new install of Ubuntu this worked but the file name was a little different. For anyone on 20.10 I first commented out the Microsoft repository by adding a `#` at the start of the line in this file `sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list.d/msprod.list' and then ran 'sudo apt update'. Then I installed the ODBC package `sudo apt-get install unixodbc` which was successful then I could run `sudo apt update` again and was then able to install the tools using `sudo apt-get install mssql-tools`.

Comment: this procedure helps me.
thanks alot @jiří-chmiel

Comment: This helped me a lot on debian 10 as well!

Answer (score 4):

User Jiří Chmiel's answer helped a lot, though I changed two lines to:

```
    sudo mv /etc/apt/sources.list.d/msprod.list ~/
```

and:

```
    sudo mv ~/msprod.list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/
```

was what worked for me
(Ubuntu 20.04 in Dec '20)

Answer (score 3):

This problems looks like you forgot to run `sudo apt-get` update before installing `odbcinst1debian2`. On *focal* this package [does not depend](https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/odbcinst1debian2) on `multiarch-support`.

*From https://askubuntu.com/questions/1232332/installing-odbcins1debian2-broken-dependency-on-ubuntu-20-04-lts*

Comment: even do update, the result is same. I tried install multarch-support manually but unable to install it. I post some tries here,

Comment: `apt-cache policy odbcinst1debian2` returns `odbcinst1debian2:
  Installed: 2.3.6-0.1build1
  Candidate: 2.3.7
  Version table:
     2.3.7 500
        500 https://packages.microsoft.com/ubuntu/18.04/prod bionic/main amd64 Packages
     2.3.7 500
        500 https://packages.microsoft.com/ubuntu/19.10/prod eoan/main amd64 Packages
 *** 2.3.6-0.1build1 500
        500 http://jp.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
`

Comment: `lsb_release -a` returns `No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description: Ubuntu 20.04 LTS
Release: 20.04
Codename: focal`

Answer (score 2):

If you follow [Microsoft install guide for SQL Server Tools](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/sql-server-linux-setup-tools?view=sql-server-ver15), for Ubuntu it says

> If you are using Ubuntu 18.04 or Ubuntu 20.04, change the repository path in step 2 below from /ubuntu/16.04 to /ubuntu/18.04 or /ubuntu/20.04

So in step 2, you should do

```
curl https://packages.microsoft.com/config/ubuntu/20.04/prod.list | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/msprod.list
```

instead of

```
curl https://packages.microsoft.com/config/ubuntu/16.04/prod.list | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/msprod.list
```

Comment: Thanks, I was able to install `mssql-tools` in Ubuntu 20.04 (which is missing in the `mssql-server-2019.list`)